# ''Having lived ''meaning

Tags: grammar

But ***having lived*** in England for the past 3 years I’ve come to realize that this may be one of the reasons people call me ‘crazy’

what does ''***having lived***'' mean in the sentence?

because I have lived ,
after I have lived
or etc?

Comment: having lived = having dwelt = I dwelt in England for a period of three years.

Answer (score 0):

AS far as I see, "Having lived in England" is similar in meaning to: *because of the fact that I have lived in England*.

A person lives or does not live in a place now in the present or in the past; it is not a continuous action. Using the gerund here in the modal verb **to have** is used to give it a meaning like the one I said before. At least, in Spanish it is the same. I can translate it literally to Spanish and it has the same meaning.

Answer (score 0):

The intent is to explain that the statement about to be made (about why people call me crazy) is based on extended, current, experience of England.

> I have lived in England for the past 3 years, and so base my answer on some knowledge and experience.

The formulation **having lived** gives a feeling of ownership; the speaker is emphasising that the experience of England is something that has been incorporated into their understanding.